# how to bind html string with ng-bind and ng-repeat for a table element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to AngularJS. I have an HTML string which I need to bind to a table element, however I get a different result during bind.

Please find jsFiddle image of  my code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Jp4.png).

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>XYZ</td>
        <!-- Direct bind using span-->
        <span><tr><td>Akshay</td></tr><tr><td>Jain</td></tr></span>
        <span><tr><td>Bangalore</td></tr></span>
        <!-- Bind using ng-bind-html-->
        <span ng-repeat="opt in opts" ng-bind-html="opt.text"></span>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $sce) {

    $scope.opts = [
        {
            value: 222,
            text: '<tr><td><i>Akshay</i></td></tr><tr><td>Jain</td></tr><tr><td>Bangalore</td></tr>'
        }
    ];

    $scope.opts[0].text = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.opts[0].text);

}
```

**Output**

```
AkshayJainBangalore
ABC XYZ
Akshay
Jain
Bangalore
```

If you can see, my code is different when i try to paint values directly in HTML and different hen i use ng-bind. Please help me know where i am going wrong.

Comment: Please add your code to the question, not an image. That being said, Angular requires safe HTML to be rendered, so inject the `$sce` module next to `$scope`, and send your html back as `$sce.trustAsHtml()`. See the [$sce docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

Comment: @SterlingArcher I have now added my code. I will fix it with $sce soon. However as you can see, my result is different when i write values directly in HTML and different when i bind it with ng-bind. Please help

Comment: `ng-bind-html-unsafe="opt.text"` you need to remove `unsafe` and do `text: $sce.trustAsHtml("table html here")` on your object.

Comment: @SterlingArcher, I have added $sce service and called its method. However i am still not getting the response. Please help